Error in Expo: Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: HMRClient.setup()
I am currently working on a React Native Expo Project. Until recently everything worked perfectly fine, but suddenly the project does not work in Android Emulator anymore ( I use Android Studio). I always get the following Error when starting the project:

 Your app just crashed. See the error below.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: HMRClient.setup()
  com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
  com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

However, in the Browser as a WebVersion it still works fine.
I already tried to empty node_modules and reinstall the modules but it did not help.
I am looking forward to your advice!

did you got the solution for it ? from outside of stackoverflow ?

I got exactly the same error, could you share if you managed to find a solution? Thanks

I got this cryptic error after inadvertently adding a top level await to the codebase. This is not supported by the commonjs modules used by RN, but the toolchain didn't catch the problem.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
